# i am tying to make a automated parking lot with a gate, sensor, button, keypad, how can i time how long has each car spent inside?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, c++

the project requires a automated parking lot, I have been able to connect and function the sensor and button for exit and enter, and the led(red lights when parking is full, green when there is spots). the maximum cars are 5. and the lcd prints the spots available and the spaces taken. the keypad is also connected. now what I need is to make a code that times each car that enters in the order that they enter in and for each car that leaves it has to enter its order of entering to calculate the price it has to pay with this equation: Parking Fee (fils) = time(sec) x 0.29fils
here is the code i have at the moment:

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12,11,5,4,3,2);
Servo myservo;

#define Servo 7
#define exit SDA
#define power 6 // extra
#define ground 10 // extra
#define capacity 5
#define R_led SCL
#define G_led 13
int val;
int n = 5;
int s = 0;

const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 3; //three columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
 {'1','2','3'},
 {'4','5','6'},
 {'7','8','9'},
 {'*','0','#'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {A4, A3, A2, A1}; //Arduino Pins
byte colPins[COLS] = {8, 9, 10}; //Arduino Pins

void setup(){
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    pinMode(rowPins[i],INPUT);  //set row pins as inputs
    pinMode(colPins[i],OUTPUT); //set column pins as outputs
  }
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myservo.attach(Servo);
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  pinMode(power,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ground,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(exit,INPUT);
  pinMode(G_led,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(R_led,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ground,LOW);
  digitalWrite(power,HIGH);
  myservo.write(0);
  digitalWrite(R_led,LOW);
  digitalWrite(G_led,LOW);  
}

void loop(){
  if (n>=1){
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(1,0);
    lcd.print("Spots left: ");
    lcd.print(n);
    lcd.setCursor(1,1);
    lcd.print("Cars inside: ");
    lcd.print(s);
    digitalWrite(G_led,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(R_led,LOW);
    delay(30);
    
  }
  else {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(1,0);
    lcd.print("The parking is");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("full!");
    digitalWrite(G_led,LOW);
    digitalWrite(R_led,HIGH);
    delay(30);    
  }
val = analogRead(A0);
// Serial.println(val); 
if (val>950)
{
  if (n!=0){
    n--;
    s++;
    myservo.write(90);
    delay(3000);
    myservo.write(0);
  }
}
if (digitalRead(exit)==1)
{
  if (n!=capacity){
    n++;
    s--;
      myservo.write(90);
    delay(3000);
    myservo.write(0);
  }
}
delay(20);
  int keyValue=0;
    digitalWrite(colPins[0],HIGH); //Set column1 as high
    digitalWrite(colPins[1],LOW);
    digitalWrite(colPins[2],LOW);
    digitalWrite(colPins[3],LOW);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){             //iterate over rows to find if key is pressed
      keyValue = digitalRead(rowPins[i]);
      if(keyValue== 1){
            //display either 1,4,7 or *
        Serial.println(keys[i][0]); //display key pressed
        delay(500);
      }
    }
    
    digitalWrite(colPins[0],LOW);
    digitalWrite(colPins[1],HIGH); //Set column2 as high
    digitalWrite(colPins[2],LOW);
    digitalWrite(colPins[3],LOW);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){              //iterate over rows to find if key is pressed
      keyValue = digitalRead(rowPins[i]);
      if(keyValue== 1){
        //display either 2,5,8,0
         Serial.println(keys[i][1]); //display key pressed
        delay(500);
      }
    }
    digitalWrite(colPins[0],LOW);
    digitalWrite(colPins[1],LOW);
    digitalWrite(colPins[2],HIGH);//Set column3 as high
    digitalWrite(colPins[3],LOW);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
      keyValue = digitalRead(rowPins[i]);
      if(keyValue== 1){               //iterate over rows to find if key is pressed
        //display either 3,6,9,#
         Serial.println(keys[i][2]); //display key pressed
        delay(500);
      }
    }
    digitalWrite(colPins[0],LOW);
    digitalWrite(colPins[1],LOW);
    digitalWrite(colPins[2],LOW);
    digitalWrite(colPins[3],HIGH);//Set column4 as high
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
      keyValue = digitalRead(rowPins[i]);
      if(keyValue== 1){               //iterate over rows to find if key is pressed
        //display either A,B,C,D
         Serial.println(keys[i][3]); //display key pressed
        delay(500);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends on the required accuracy. You can use `millis()` to measure time, though it is not very accurate depending on the internal clock. If you need correct time you need to use a Real Time Clock module (RTC). How accurate should it be? What time ranges do you want to measure?

Comment: yes I want to use millis(), but I can't figure how to do it on the requirements I mentioned above

Comment: the range is when the car enters the parking until it exits

Comment: some of your code makes no sense ... it seems that you are not thinking clearly about your program ... why are you scanning the keypad? ... look at Keypad library examples

Comment: just do what a real parking lot does, record the arrival time

Comment: ok can you please let me know how to record the arrival time ? I would really appreciate it

Comment: When using `millis()`, the arrival time is the return value of `millis()` at the time of arrival. Thats what `millis()` does. It gives you the number of milliseconds since startup, thus time. When someone arrives, save the value of `millis()` in a variable. Later you can subtract that value from `millis()` and get the time of stay in milliseconds.

Comment: yes I understand that but I want to know how to count the time for different cars at the same time, to be more precise 5 cars and each car when it leaves it enters the number of order it entered in to calculate the fee

Comment: do this on paper first ... draw the parking lot with 5 spaces ... use pieces of paper to represent vehicles ... write down everything that you need to keep track of ... translate into a program

Comment: @FaisalAlrafaei did you write the code that you presented?

Comment: firstly about drawing there is no need for it because I am using tinkercad, secondly the code I collected information I found on the internet and edited them

Comment: @FaisalAlrafaei With drawing on paper jsotola wanted to guide you to solve the problem yourself. Often programming questions can be solved, when you make yourself clear what the exact steps in a process are. These steps then can be translated to code way easier. Tinkercad doesn't do that for you and you don't seem to have every step of the process in mind.

Comment: ok, use toy cars instead, but write down all the information that you need in order to charge for the correct time of each parked vehicle

Comment: `code I collected information I found on the internet and edited them` ... you really need to learn what the code actually does ... the sketch has a lot of un-necessary code

Answer (score 1):

For measuring the time for each parking lot:

Declare an array of `unsigned long` with one element per parking lot (so 5 in this case) and initialize it with zeros:

```
#define N_PARKING_LOTS 5
unsigned long timestamps[N_PARKING_LOTS] = {0};
```

Then go to the place in your code where a new car arrives in its parking lot. You need the number of the used parking lot. Set the corresponding element in the array to `millis()` (for example here element 3, so the 4th parking lot):

```
timestamps[3] = millis();
```

When the corresponding car leaves you can get the time by calculating the difference and by that calculate the price:

```
unsigned long park_duration = millis() - timestamp[3];
float price = (park_duration/1000)*0.29;
```

How you know the parking lot depends on your actual process. It is difficult to understand what you want to say in your question. You could guide the arriving car to a parking spot chosen by you.

Btw: The code will get much easier for you when you actually use the `Keypad` library, instead of just including it. Then your current code will get way shorter.

Comment: How do you know which car is which. You could use a long range RFID tag in each one then when sensing you will know who and your clock will tell you when and you hopefully know if it is coming or going. After that you should be able to work the code.